# Is there any way to generate `monitors.xml` programmatically?

Tags: gnome3, monitors, display-settings

I use a script in order to setup my system in an unattended fashion.

On my last reinstall, I've found that the file `~/.config/monitors.xml` is not created automatically. While I can create it by opening the Displays program (I'm on Ubuntu), I'd like to create it programmatically (then modify it separately).

Is it possible to create it programmatically, with the default values (that is, like if I opened the Displays program, and clicked on Apply)?